# UNIX Shell Kill Command

Tags: shell, unix, sh

My script to kill the process contains just this

```
#!/bin/sh

kill -SIGKILL 3590
```

I get `./xx.sh: line 3: kill: SIGKILL: invalid signal specification`

But the same command working fine in the shell and kill -9 3590 working fine in the script as well.

Comment: Drop the SIG: `kill -KILL 3590`

Comment: Great!. It works.... Why was that?

Comment: 'They' decided that forcing users to write SIG was a bad idea (probably correct) and didn't consider making the SIG optional (perhaps a less good idea).  Also, `kill` in Bash is a built-in; see [Bash POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode); one of the bullets identifies the SIG prefix as being supported by `bash` and not by `sh`.  The external command probably doesn't support the SIG prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If the script is behaving differently from the same command in a terminal, it's probably because they're using two different shells.

Just a guess, here, but I'm going to assume that shell in your terminal is bash and `/bin/sh` points to something else. Try changing the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: To go with this, `bash` makes `kill` a shell builtin (to allow you to kill a process even if the process table is too full to create a process for running `/bin/kill`), but `kill` is not required to be a builtin according to the POSIX spec. (Oops, this pretty  much just repeats what Jonathan Leffler said in a question comment.)